# Universal path in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, time-machine, applescript

I'm writing an AppleScript that will allow me to copy the Time Machine folder from an external drive and paste it onto the user's desktop of their Mac. The reason I'm doing this is because when a time machine backup isn't working as it should, we have to manually move it. Well, I'd like to make this process easier for people and just create a script to do it.

tl;dr problem:
How do I make a variable location?

Ex: /Volumes/Time\ Machine/Backups.backupdb///Users

The X and Y are going to be different for everyone's Mac. People have different names for their macs and Hard Drives. How could I make a universal location? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `~` shortcut or `$HOME` variable, both of which refer to the User's home directory. You can try this out in Terminal by running `cd ~` or `cd $HOME`, which will take you to your home directory. You can verify by running `pwd`, which should output `/Users/` followed by your username.

For the Desktop, you would use `~/Desktop` or `$HOME/Desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the machine name with `scutil --get ComputerName` and the name of the boot volume with

```
basename "`find -x /Volumes/ -type l`"
```

Note that both of these may well return a string containing spaces. So you want to do this

```
COMPUTER="`scutil --get ComputerName`"
VOLUME="`basename \"\`find -x /Volumes/ -type l\`\""
```

then

```
TIMEPATH="/Volumes/Time Machine/Backups.backupdb/$COMPUTER/$VOLUME/Users"
```